# Clang - removing "conversion function converting <A> to base class <B> will never be used" warnings for certain files

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, clang

Clang kind of chokes on DirectX's include files, and spits a handful of warnings, like these when analyzing the headers:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include\D3D11.h:1133,5 - Warning - conversion function converting 'CD3D11_RECT' to its base class 'tagRECT' will never be used
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include\D3D11.h:1179,5 - Warning - conversion function converting 'CD3D11_BOX' to its base class 'D3D11_BOX' will never be used
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include\D3D11.h:1441,5 - Warning - conversion function converting 'CD3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC' to its base class 'D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC' will never be used
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include\D3D11.h:1661,5 - Warning - conversion function converting 'CD3D11_BLEND_DESC' to its base class 'D3D11_BLEND_DESC' will never be used
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include\D3D11.h:1857,5 - Warning - conversion function converting 'CD3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC' to its base class 'D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC' will never be used
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include\D3D11.h:2200,5 - Warning - conversion function converting 'CD3D11_BUFFER_DESC' to its base class 'D3D11_BUFFER_DESC' will never be used
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include\D3D11.h:2400,5 - Warning - conversion function converting 'CD3D11_TEXTURE1D_DESC' to its base class 'D3D11_TEXTURE1D_DESC' will never be used
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include\D3D11.h:2608,5 - Warning - conversion function converting 'CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC' to its base class 'D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC' will never be used
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include\D3D11.h:2811,5 - Warning - conversion function converting 'CD3D11_TEXTURE3D_DESC' to its base class 'D3D11_TEXTURE3D_DESC' will never be used
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include\D3D11.h:3419,5 - Warning - conversion function converting 'CD3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC' to its base class 'D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC' will never be used
```

Of course, this makes it quite annoying to step through all of this to find the Errors and Warnings interesting me. Is there a flag which would make it not output these messages, or at least a way to not analyze the DirectX header files ?

I'm currently compiling with

```
-Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-microsoft -Wno-return-type-c-linkage -Wno-conversions -IC:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include -IC:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include
```

Comment: Silly question--why are you using Clang on Windows? Any particular reason?

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 2 with the SublimeClang plugin. I know that I could go with Visual Studio (which is what I was doing before), but I'd like to make it work, just 'cause. I know that compiling anything Win32 related with any other compiler than vc.exe is painful.

Comment: Is modifying those files an option?

Comment: @MichałGórny: Modifying the DirectX header files ? It can be done, yeah, but I'd rather find another option.

Comment: Does clang have a directive to mark an include directory as a system include directory, like gcc's `-isystem` instead of `-I`, and to suppress warnings from system headers?

Comment: @hvd: ding ding ding, we have a winner. That did work. Thank you.

Comment: Could you post that as an answer (with the actual option that you ended up using) for the benefit of others with the same question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, for anyone that might have this 'problem' too:

Don't use `-I<path>`, use `-isystem<path>`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find the appropriate `-Wno-` option to turn off this error message. If you're actually developing a library that uses void conversion operators, this error message is irritating.